# Remote shutdown Ubuntu 20.04 with Google Home

Tags: scripts, shutdown, startup, dropbox, remote

I want to tell Google Home to shutdown my Ubuntu 20.04 machine. I have followed this guide:
[How can I remotely shutdown Ubuntu using Google Home?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146814/how-can-i-remotely-shutdown-ubuntu-using-google-home)

If I run the script mentioned in the post manually and change the dropbox file, everything is fine.
Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          filenotifier
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Something
# Description:       Something else
### END INIT INFO
cd /home/YOUR_USER_NAME/Dropbox/RemoteTurnOff
inotifywait -e close_write,moved_to,create -m . |
while read -r directory events filename; do
  if [ "$filename" = "fileToWatch.txt" ]; then
    systemctl poweroff
  fi
done
```

My problem is that it won't work when restarting.

I've tried the rc.local thing. Wouldn't work.

I've tried to create a systemd shutdown.service like so:

```
[Unit]
Description=Job that runs shutdown script

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/myusername/Dropbox/RemoteTurnOff/script.sh
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

It's in /etc/systemd/system

I created this service, then did

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable shutdown.service
```

If I check if the service is running with

```
sudo systemctl status shutdown.service
```

It says that it's running, Watches established.

However, if I try changing the dropbox file it doesn't shutdown.

Does anyone have an idea as what I could do?

Comment: If you are the only user logged in *locally*, the shutdown command does not require sudo. However, if there are multiple user logged in OR if you are logged using ssh, then shutdown requires sudo.

Comment: Check `dropbox status`. Does the filesystem of `/home/YOUR_USER_NAME/Dropbox/` support `iwatch`? Use ` lsblk -f`

Comment: Yes it does. The script works fine when I manually start it. But it does not work when I restart the machine and the systemd service starts it.